# How run package goal after finished integration tests in maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, integration-testing

The default build maven cycle is like that:

1. compile
2. test
3. package
4. pre-intergation-test
5. intergation-test
6. post-intergation-test
7. verify
8. install

On `pre-intergation-test` a database is started. The `intergation-test` is spring tests, when piece of application is started and tested against database. On `post-intergation-test` database is shutdown.

So for that scenario it is not needed to package entire application, is there a way to package application **after** verify goal?

Comment: The Maven meaning of integration-test is, that it run against the builded (packaged) artefact:

>integration-test - process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run

(https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) ---- so my advice would be trying the other way around: instead of distort the maven live cycle, I would try to make your tests run in the maven test-phase

Comment: The question is: What do you mean by `it is not needed to package entire application`? Your using of integration test phase is exactly as intended...Are we talking about a web application ? And what exactly are you doing in the integration test phase? Can you show a pom file?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the integration-test phase in maven life-cycle is to test the packaged artifact. So it don't make sense to try to execute integration-test before the package phase.

On the other hand, you have the test-phase to execute the unit tests. If you follow the strict definition of unit-tests : they shouldn't require a database. In other words, during unit-test execution: database should be mocked.

As far as I understand your situation, you have unit-tests that requires a database. This is not a perfect design, in ideal world you should consider re-design your unit-tests to use a mock instead of a database.

But you can also use kind of intermediate solution where you start/stop the database before/after the test phase. [Here is the full life-cycle reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html) and as you can see you can bind your database startup to `generate-test-resources` phase. (I don't recommend this solution, because your unit-tests became heavy to run and running them from within your IDE became also a bit more complex since it requires to execute a maven phase)

An alternative solution commonly used is to setup a small in memory database in the tests themselves. It is very easy with spring and here is a sample test configuration to demonstrate that :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class UnitTestWithDBConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
                .addScript("dbsetup.sql")
                .build();
    }

}
```

This sample use h2 database + a src/test/resources/dbsetup.sql file to initialize your database (when application context is loaded).